# How do I define a parent class method that when invoked from a subclass defines methods on that subclass?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, metaprogramming

I want to do something like the following, where Parent.setupMethod would create both instance methods on the subclass (only) as well as class methods. Is this possible?

```
class Parent
  @setupMethod: (name) ->
    # do whatever to setup method on calling class


class Child1 extends Parent
  @setupMethod "someMethod"

class Child2 extends Parent

child1 = new Child1
child2 = new Child2

child1.someMethod # some output
child2.someMethod # undefined
```

Comment: Can you describe what `someMethod` will be doing please, and why you need to define it programatically rather than statically?

Comment: @Jon: I'm guessing that it is something like a Rails-style macro along the lines of the `before_filter`, `has_many`, ... class methods.

Comment: Correct, in that I'm looking at something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want `setupMethod` to be a Ruby-style macro that adds methods to `Child1`. All you need to do for that is edit the appropriate prototype inside `Parent.setupMethod`, for example:

```
class Parent
  @setupMethod: (name) ->
    @::[name] = -> # whatever needs to be done goes here...
```

In the context of a class method such as `Parent.setupMethod`, `@` will be the class itself and `@::` will be the corresponding JavaScript prototype (i.e. `@::` is where the instance methods for `@` live). Then you add the appropriate property to the `@::` object and you're done.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/m2y22/

Comment: This works if define @setupMethod with => instead of ->.  I get undefined functions, otherwise.  But I'd like to not define the instance method on the instances of every subclass.  Is this possible? So in the fiddle child1 has the method, but child2 errors?

Comment: But the `child2.someMethod # undefined` in your question suggests that `Child2` shouldn't get the `someMethod`, only `Child1` should get it. That's exactly what happens in the fiddle, no? If you define `setupMethod` with `=>` then it will add the method to `Parent`.

Comment: That is what I want for Child1 and Child2, but without the need for the if/else in the subclass.  Also, I switched back to -> and it does look like the function is defined correctly.  The undefined method error is on the Parent class now, oddly.  Not sure where I'm calling these methods on the parent so will have to trace through a bit.

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at. Can you provide a better example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Currently, if the Child1 class extends Parent and uses the setupMethod macro to define "someMethod", I can then call "someMethod" on all instances of Child1 -- great.  What I don't want, however, is for instances of Child2, which did not define "someMethod" to be able to call "someMethod."  I am looking for this behavior without the need for the "if('someMethod' of c1)" check.  Make sense?

Comment: So you want `obj.m()` to return `undefined` if there is no method `m` defined on `obj`? Or are you expecting an action in `Child1` to alter the behavior of its sibling class `Child2`?

Comment: Yes, the former case.  If obj is an instance of Child2 and Child2 does not have setupMethod "someMethod", then obj should respond with undefined.  What I don't want is for actions with @setupMethod on Child1 to affect Child2.

Comment: Then why not add `someMethod: ->` to the base class and then override it in Child1? Otherwise, `@superMethod 'someMethod'` **will** be altering Child2. I think you might want to completely rethink what you're doing, sounds like you're trying to do something rather bizarre. Perhaps you should start again by stating the underlying problem rather than the proposed solution.